# Creating a Prolog Query and Answer System

Tags: prolog

I'm learning prolog and I've been stuck on a problem. I'm making a question and and answer system.
For example, When I type, "The color of the car is blue." The program will say "OK" and add that new rule, so when asked, "What is the color of the car?" It'll respond with blue.
If I say "the color of the car is green," it'll reply with "Its not."
But whenever I type "The color of the car is blue" it returns true, false for the question version. Can someone direct on where to go further? I don't know how to get the program to say "its blue" or anything

```
 input :-
    read_line_to_codes(user_input, Input),
    string_to_atom(Input,Atoms),
    atomic_list_concat(Alist, ' ', Atoms),
    phrase(sentence(S), Alist),    
    process(S).

statement(Statement) --> np(Description), np(N), ap(A),
{ Statement =.. [Description, N, A]}.

query(Fact) -->  qStart, np(A), np(N),
 { Fact =.. [A, N, X]}.


np(Noun) --> det, [Noun], prep.
np(Noun) --> det, [Noun].

ap(Adj) --> verb, [Adj].
qStart --> adjective, verb.

vp --> det, verb.   

adjective --> [what].
det --> [the].

prep --> [of].

verb -->[is].


%% Combine grammar rules into one sentence
sentence(statement(S)) --> statement(S).
sentence(query(Q)) --> query(Q).
process(statement(S)) :- asserta(S).
process(query(Q))     :- Q.
```

Comment: Y U no trace your query and see wat is wrong? Instead of `?- Query.` just write `?- trace, Query.` and step through it. But but but please do not ignore warnings I know they are just warning but if you ignore warnings and even ignore errors and then you just come to Stackoverflow then if someone warns you that you are making a mistake what is the difference?

Comment: You have several *singleton* variable warnings and a syntax error, so those need to be resolved before making much further progress.

Comment: I've taken out the errors, except for description because I'm not sure what I should change that to.  I don't need that variable.  Can someone direct me from my original question?

Answer (score 1):

You're actually really close. Take a look at this:

```
?- phrase(sentence(Q), [what,is,the,color,of,the,car]).
Q = query(color(car, _6930)) ;
false.
```

You've successfully parsed the sentence into a query there. Now let's process it:

```
?- phrase(sentence(Q), [what,is,the,color,of,the,car]), process(Q).
Q = query(color(car, 'blue.')) ;
false.
```

As you can see, you properly unified. You just didn't do anything with it when you were done. I think all you need to do is pass the result of `process/1` into something to display the result:

```
display(statement(S)) :- format('~w added to database~n', [S]).
display(query(Q)) :- Q =.. [Rel, N, X], format('the ~w has ~w ~w~n', [N, Rel, X]).
```

And modify `input/0` to pass to the `display/1` predicate:

```
input :-
    read_line_to_codes(user_input, Input),
    string_to_atom(Input,Atoms),
    atomic_list_concat(Alist, ' ', Atoms),
    phrase(sentence(S), Alist),    
    process(S),
    display(S).
```

Now you get some results when you use it:

```
?- phrase(sentence(Q), [what,is,the,color,of,the,car]), process(Q), display(Q).
the car has color blue.
Q = query(color(car, 'blue.')) ;
false.

?- phrase(sentence(Q), [the,siding,of,the,car,is,steel]), process(Q), display(Q).
siding(car,steel) added to database
Q = statement(siding(car, steel)) ;
false.

?- phrase(sentence(Q), [what,is,the,siding,of,the,car]), process(Q), display(Q).
the car has siding steel
Q = query(siding(car, steel)) ;
false.
```